# Ruby mail APIs that can send an email to a phone

Tags: ruby, email, sendmail

I am trying to write a program in Ruby that can send a email to a phone. Outside of the program, I am able to do this by sending an email to xxx-xxx-xxxx@vtext.com or any other carrier in my Apple Mail client, and it worked fine; it sends a text message to the targeted phone, but when I tried to use a Ruby API (I forget the name), that used sendmail, to send a message, it would not send the message. Are there any ruby APIs that can send an email to a phone? (Or can someone just list some different Ruby mail APIs that I can try)?

Comment: Is your `sendmail` configured properly?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I have never used sendmail before, so it's quite possible that it's not. All I can say is that it is set whatever settings are used on Mac OS 10.6 Snow Leopard.

Comment: I don't believe the Apple Mail client uses sendmail to send mail.

Comment: I know and that's why I can send emails to phones. Does anyone know of any APIs that don't use sendmail to send their email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used ActionMailer and Pony (http://github.com/benprew/pony) in the past.

Answer (score 0):

it should "just work" assuming your mailing system/settings are setup right.